# Solo Learn practice how to calculate parking fee based on some conditions in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

You are making a car parking software that needs to calculate and output the amount due based on the number of hours the car was parked.
The fee is calculated based on the following price structure:

- the first 5 hours are billed at $1 per hour.
- after that, each hour is billed at $0.5 per hour.
- for each 24 hours, there is a flat fee of $15.

This means, that, for example, if a car parked for 26 hours, the bill should be 15+(2*0.5) = 16.0, because it was parked for 24 hours plus 2 additional hours.

Sample Input:
8

Sample Output:
6.5

Explanation: The first 5 hours are billed at $1/hour, which results in $5. After that, the next 3 hours are billed at $0.5/hour = $1.5.
So, the total would be $5+$1.5 = $6.5

**Below code works fine however it doesn't satisfy all conditions which are hidden**

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    var hours = readLine()!!.toInt()
    var total: Double = 0.0
    total = when{
        hours <= 5 -> {
            val cost = hours *1.toDouble()
            cost
        }
        hours in 6..23 -> {
            val cost = 5 + (hours - 5) * 0.5
            cost
        }
        hours == 24 -> {
            val cost = 15.toDouble ()
            cost 
        }
        else -> {
            val cost = 15 + (hours -24) * 0.5
            cost
        }
    }
    println(total )
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One case that I think you missed is that, for `hours > 24` you always use $15, while as per the question it is $15 per day, so you need to multiply it by the number of days.

Try this code:

```kotlin
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val hours = readLine()!!.toInt()
    val total = when {
        hours >= 24 -> 15 * (hours / 24) + 0.5 * (hours % 24)
        hours > 5 -> 5 + (hours - 5) * 0.5
        else -> hours.toDouble()
    }
    println(total)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```kotlin
fun main (args : Array<String>) {
    var hour = readLine()!!.toInt()
    var total = when {
        hour >= 24 -> (15 * (hour/24)) + (0.5 * (hour%24))
        hour > 5 && hour <24 -> 5 + ((hour-5)*0.5)
        else -> hour.toDouble()
    }
    println(total)
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).